# .sheet modifier changes background color on ListView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug. I'm running Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.1.  This wasn't happening on Xcode 11.

The code is as follows:

```
enum SheetView: Identifiable {
    var id: SheetView { self }
    case add
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items = ["Book", "Cat", "Dog"]
    @State private var sheetView: SheetView?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button(action: {
                        sheetView = .add
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Add")
                    })
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $sheetView, onDismiss: { sheetView = nil }) { sheet in
                if sheet == .add {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: attach the `.sheet` to the `NavigationView` instead of the `List`

Comment: @vacawama thank you. I thought we arent suppose to attach anything to it.